# Fabric dispatchCommands should go through the JSI API - this will crash in Fabric

Tags: javascript, react-native

when newArchitecture is enabled my react native android app throws error dispatch command called without surfaceid - Fabric dispatchCommands should go through the JSI API at UIManagerModule.java

Comment: Any updates here?